# Can I get the Logged User's Email & Phone and populate them into List's Form?

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, list-form

In my Office 365 (SharePoint Online) I have a very simple Custom List which consists of a bunch of columns/fields, and I have a requirement that when a user clicks on: Add New Item, The logged user's name or email address will be populated into a PeoplePicker field (EmployeeName), and the logged user's phone number will be populated into another SingleLineText field called (EmployeePhone). Other fields will be filled manually by the user.

How can I accomplish this? Could you please share with me some code/scripts?

[image]

For getting the user\s email address and populating it into a PeoplePicker field (EmployeeName) I have used the script below. But, I am not happy with it as it only works with IE, But, NOT other browsers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(setLoginName, "clientpeoplepicker.js");
    });

    function setLoginName() {
        var loginName = _spPageContextInfo.userLoginName;
        var peoplePickerDiv = $("[id$='ClientPeoplePicker'][title='EmployeeName']");
        var peoplePickerEditor = peoplePickerDiv.find("[title='EmployeeName']");
        var spPeoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[peoplePickerDiv[0].id];
        peoplePickerEditor.val(loginName);
        spPeoplePicker.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);
    }
 </script>
```

I would really appreciate if you could help me to get these two values from user's profile, Delve, or anywhere as long as the code is something I can put inside a Script Editor web part.

Thank you very much.